# PLupload can add files but blocks when I choose to upload

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, plupload

I am using Gravity Advanced Files uploader plugin for wordpress which use PLupload for file uploads.

I want it to allow .bmp and .dcm files to be uploaded. I was able to change the settings to allow those files types to be added with plupload by adding the file extension and also to the mime type list. But when I press start upload it comes back with those files as having a "file type error".

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The issue was actually the wordpress media library blocking those file types. I added this code to me funcitons.php file and problem solved.

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1 );
function my_myme_types( $mime_types ) {
   $mime_types['dcm'] = 'application/dicom'; // Adding dicom images    extension
   $mime_types['bmp'] = 'image/bmp'; 
   return $mime_types;
}
```